# Can a vampire use mental disciplines while staked?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

If my info is correct, impaling a vampire's heart in oWoD paralyzes it until the stake (or whatever) is removed. Could he still use mental disciplines such as Auspex or Dominate?

Comment: The "whatever" still needs to be made from wood and impale the heart, even if it isn't an object we might call a stake.  So, a wooden pencil, chair leg, or wooden baseball bat would do but a piece of steel re-bar wouldn't.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A vampire immobilized by a wooden stake "is conscious (and may use perception powers, such as those in the Auspex Discipline), but may not move or spend blood points." (p.280, V20)

So, Auspex is definitely okay. Use of Dominate is potentially possible, but would require a power that neither requires you to speak (can't move) or make eye contact (because when you can't move, it's easy to avoid a vampire's gaze). If you've got Auspex up to 5 *and* Dominate, it's possible to overcome this problem—a manifest Psychic Projection can use Dominate with at least 3 successes on the initial Projection roll.

Elder level abilities open up even wider vistas: The Dominate level 6 power Obedience would allow for this if the character's skin is touched. Light and even brief touches will suffice. When handling a staked Kindred it's hard to avoid skin contact unless explicitly stating it.

Comment: Specifically, can do any non-blood spending action you can do while astral projecting is my understanding.

Comment: It's been answered a while ago, but thought I'd leave this here in case anyone is interested. The Dominate level 6 power Obedience would allow for this if the character's skin is touched. Light and even brief touches will suffice. When handling a staked Kindred it's hard to avoid skin contact unless explicitly stating it. And then there's other ways to deliberately get them to touch him, a Rolex that's just waiting to get stolen or that ancient looking necklace or ring  that looks like it has some powers or value...